# How to quickly export table structure from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 to Visio to make an ERD?

Tags: sql, database, import, export, visio

I have a database with several tables in it (about 100). Is there any sort of quick way to take the information about each table (or specific tables selected by me) and put it in a Visio format? I've seen a lot of information on how to export an ERD to a SQLServer schema, but I need to go the other way.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Visio to do that! It's a built-in functionality documented in [Visio manual](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/visio-help/reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-HA010115485.aspx):

Video tutorials are also available (take a look at this one for example, it's rather old, but there were no fundamental changes): [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5CEABZKuMM), [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWT8IavmqcI)

Mind that you'll need professional edition of Visio. Also mind that this functionality (reverse engineer) was dropped in Visio 2013 (i.e. you can use Visio 2003-2010 to accomplish that, but not the 2013)

Comment: why on earth would MS get rid of that feature?!?! just inherited a mess of a DB, VS10 saved me a lot of time

Comment: @dier because of the very negative user feedback, they have brought it back in the latest version, as a separate extension: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54527

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but if you expand the database, and right click on "Database Diagrams" and select "New Diagram", you can select the tables, and it will create a diagram for you based on the tables, keys, and relationships.  It's a fairly user-friendly design, and while there's no way to export that to Visio or anything like that (as far as I'm aware), it can at least give you an idea of your database layout.